# How to deploy a Django project generated by Cookie cutter to Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, cookiecutter-django

So I'm following a book named Django Crash Course by the Greenfelds.

Here's the starter template they used.
https://github.com/feldroy/django-crash-starter

So this project template generates a Django version of 3.1.1 with Python 3.8.

I tried to use Amazon Linux and Amazon Linux 2 on generating an environment on Elastic Beanstalk, both had 502 Bad gateway error. I have no idea how to fix since I'm still learning.

I'm curious how can I use this template for production ready to Elastic Beanstalk.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From [this issue](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/issues/1417), the maintainer decided not to support it to reduce the maintenance burden of the project.

You can try out these options, but it's noted as [experimental](https://cookiecutter-django-webspired.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployment-with-elastic-beanstalk.html) and [quite old](https://github.com/dolphinkiss/cookiecutter-django-aws-eb)

Comment: Please note that StackOverflow answers a expected to still make sense if all links are ignored. Your post shrinks to "They are not officially supporting it. There are other options. Keywords are cookiecutter, elastic beanstalk." Actually I accept that this DOES provide some answering info, i.e. this is an acceptable answer, though cutting it somewhat thinly... Just note the URL-ignoring concept please. Have fun.